# VSCode will not show context options when using scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, vs-code

I have set up a few scratch orgs, but am running into an issue with VSCode. When connected to a "normal" developer org, I am shown various options and context menus (eg, deploy manifest etc). When I am connected to a scratch org, all context options go away.

I've already tried logging out and re-authorizing the scratch org with a username/password, but that had no effect.

How can I fix this?

Screenshots. When in context of scratch org:
[image]

When in context of a regular org:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work-around I noticed that seems to have worked for me is:

1. Generate a password for your scratch org user via

`sfdx force:user:password:generate`

2. Perform a web authentication via SFDX

`sfdx force:auth:web:login --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com`

3. RESTART VSCODE and re-open the project. Metadata/tools now show up.

This feels like a bug - EG, after the weblogin credentials are set, metadata tools should become available automatically without having to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

This is as per the [design](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/blob/develop/packages/salesforcedx-vscode-core/package.json). If you need this capability and have feedback I suggest raising it on the project [github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode).

You can use the issue tab to describe your need and that would let the product team consider and prioritize it.

Comment: I think this [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1510) is asking for the same thing already.

Comment: I suggest leaving a comment to get more attention. Now the sandboxes will have source tracking capability so it might be relevant. I think the other problem in allowing was will customers understand "source tracking" and non-scratch orgs which I think slowly community is adopting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in VS Code is to open the command palette and choose "Developer: Restart Extension Host" so you don't have to close and re-open the editor.

[image]